# vue-router child route scroll position handling with hash mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using hash mode in my vue-cli application. Further, I have child routes on one route.

```
<template>
  <div style="position: relative;">    
   some other code which are common between two child routes
    </div>
    <div class='container' ref="container" >
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Scroll position is not resetting to zero (window) when I navigate between the child routes and it's producing the unexpected scrolls. further, as mentioned above I could not handle it via

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    // return desired position
  }
```

as I am not using history mode.

So, I have written below code in child routes to handle scroll position,

```
created () {
  var oContainer = document.querySelector('.container')
  oContainer.scrollTop = 0
},
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  var oContainer = document.querySelector('.container')
  oContainer.scrollTop = 0
  next()
},
```

and It's working as I need (resetting scroll position for child route to zero)
However, I don't find it appropriate because

- Exposing query selector in vue-cli instead of using
  this.$refs.container (but I am not able to get any value in $refs
  even in child mount() method)
- In one routing navigation (not in all), I want to reapply the
  scroll position when user come back to that child route.

is there any other way around to solve this problem?